# URL "http://hello.com/index.php?id=1" Redirecting if there is no "?id=1" using php

Tags: php

I have this a .php file (Currently Empty) Having some troubles:

http://example.com/index.php

I want to use PhP to redirect them to the page "/not.php" IF they don't have "?id=" at the end of the URL.

Comment: `if(empty($_GET['id'])){...}`

Comment: I hate using empty(), since id=0 would return true... strlen() is somewhat more reliable in this case, since everything in $_GET is a string anyways.